# How can I make a "local" mywebsite.test on a remote server work with SSL from my local computer?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, port-forwarding, xubuntu

I have a XUbuntu server that I can connect to via XFCE and load https://mywebsite.test with a valid local certificate I created using mkcert.

However, connecting via XFCE makes the website lag a lot, and it would be much more convenient if I could just open https://mywebsite.test from my local computer instead. But, the SSL certificate is not valid unless I open the website from the XUbuntu server itself (obviously). I need SSL certificate to be valid because I need to connect between https://mywebsite.test and https://anotherwebsite.test, and I need SSL to work on both websites.

I know these mkcert certificates are meant to be used locally, and they do work "locally", but I was wondering.. is it possible to make this work the way I want, where the certificate is in my XUbuntu server and I'm able to browse those websites with working SSL from my Mac instead of using XFCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the certificate file (you call it "mkcert certificate" but even better name would be a "self-signed certificate"). Then add that file to your Mac so that it becomes trusted (that is, trusted to secure the https connections). There are many answers on superuser.com about how to do that, for example [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1359755/trust-self-signed-cert-in-chrome-macos-10-13).

If you'd like to use mkcert for that task, they [briefly touch that in their readme](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert#installing-the-ca-on-other-systems).

And, make sure your laptop resolves the name `mywebsite.test` to the correct IP address, which is routable from your laptop. If it isn't routable, you could work around it by using one, two or twelve ssh tunnels.

Comment: Yes! that's what I was looking for. Thanks!